# Views: How to overlay?

Tags: iphone

I want to use a UIProgressView but I want the background to be an image to make things a bit more good looking. I'm not sure how to lay one over the other. It would be important for the background image to encompass the UIProgressView.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a `UIImageView` for your background image, then add a `UIProgressView` as a sub view.

You can do this in either Interface Builder or in code such as `[myBackgroundImageView addSubView:myProgressView];`

Obviously you will need to setup the correct frame for both to ensure they are in the correct position.

Check out [addSubview: in the Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

Comment: In IB you can just drop an UIImageView onto your view, then drop a UIProgressView onto the UIImageView (this is equivalent to calling  addSubView in code).